# How to detect the first load of certain page in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know how to detect session start event:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
  if (!current) {
    // handle session start event
  }
});
```

But how to detect first load of certain page? I mean how to detect that user visits e.g. page `Contacts` at first time after global refresh?

Comment: When do you visit Contacts page, the controller is get initialized. So can handle your call there.

Comment: It is desirable to detect it when the app runs in `$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart"...` func

Comment: Run block does not execute your code on route change, this is done because you are listening the route event. You can use  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart") in your controller too. Run block get execute just after config block where all providers are built.